# Can I skip chest day completely?

Tags: bodybuilding, gym, chest

I am a 18 yo male and I started going to the gym. I have only 3 days/week for working out. I am a combination of skinny, fat and muscle:)) I stand at 1,76 meters and I weight 68 kg. I decided to do: -1st day: back; -2nd day: legs and abs; -3rd day: shoulders, traps and forearm; Do you think it's enough for building some muscle? Or should I add chest day? Or maybe can I include only pushups at home as chest day?

EDIT: I have scoliosis, and kyphosis and my doctor recommended me to do either swimming or light weight exercises at gym. So, I want to strenghten my back and also to achieve a nice muscular body but not with heavy weights...

Comment: I'd recommend getting a tried and true program rather than try to make your own, if you're a beginner.

Comment: As it stands, your question could be closed as being opinion based, as there are two answers - Yes and no, and each is just someone's opinion. If you could edit it to add why you are working out, and what you want to accomplish then you could get better answers and avoid the question being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always skip any muscle forever, but you should know that you will develop a disproportionate body. A good split you could apply to you 3 times a a week schedule could be pulling-upper/pushing-upper/lower in muscles that should be shoulders, chest, triceps/back, biceps, abs/legs, calves

Answer (score 1):

Given your back issues and your doctors advice I'd be hesitant to try most traditional lifting programs. Instead you may want to look at calisthenics due to the decreased risk and lessened strain on the skeleton and joints. There are a lot of good bodyweight workout plans out there and in head to heads they can produce similar results strength wise particularly if you're just looking to build muscle to be in shape and not necessarily to look huge.

Answer (score 1):

I would be hesitant on skipping such a major group of muscles consistently and while in the short term it may not seem to be an issue, long term you are going to start to notice some posture issues once your back is developed but your chest becomes a concave void.

If you are worried about lifting heavy on your chest there is very little risk using mid range weight with dumbbells on a bench. If you feel out of control just drop the weights. (No bar is going to crash onto your chest.)